# INSERT HTML markup using before selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter

```
#twitter-widget-0 li div.header::before{
    content: '<div> <img src="images/home/twt-icon.png"> </div>';
}
```

I want to insert the specified HTML using HTML's before selector.

But it shows markup as it is.

Actually it is a `Twitter Embedded Widget` created with https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new  and I want to show that image on every tweet.

I tried it with JQuery too but with JQuery it does not append anything.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("debug1");
        $("#twitter-widget-0 li div.header").prepend('<div class="boxthreelefts-right" style="    text-align: eig;"> <img src="images/home/twt-icon.png"> </div>');

});
```

Comment: pseudo selector like `::before` is not supported by jQuery.

Comment: Very bad idea, you should rather set the image as a background of :before selector with proper display attribute, width and height

Comment: about jquery code : it works https://jsfiddle.net/g57xfn70/ , but your inline styles doesn't exists...

Comment: @demo but it does not work at my side

Comment: @Umair, some errors in console?

Comment: Nah ... I can see `debug1`

Comment: @Umair is your twitter code inside iframe or on your page?

Comment: @Shelim yes in Iframe

Comment: @Umair you can not manipulate content inside iframe using javascript or jquery DOM manipulation scripts as it is cross domain.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (if your code not inside iframe):

I tested it works (In page):

```
    <div id="twitter-widget-0">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="header"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="header"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="header"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#twitter-widget-0 li div.header').each(function(key,value){
            $(this).before('<div class="boxthreelefts-right" style="text-align: eig;"> <img src="images/home/twt-icon.png"> </div>');
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by CSS and jQuery, 
but unfortunately `content:` does not support HTML

content syntax is like below :

```
content: normal|none|counter|attr|string|open-quote|close-quote|no-open-quote|no-close-quote|url|initial|inherit;
```

as it does not support HTML, you can give it URL and set it's position

like this

```
content:url('images/home/twt-icon.png');
```

But I recommend using jQuery to append HTML to the elements.